# COM+ long running method causing other methods to block/hang

Tags: .net, multithreading, com, apartments

I have a long running COM+ method that I need to be able to cancel from another thread. I am using C#/.NET to interact the COM+ objects. I configured both COM+ objects to have a "Free" threading model. This C# sample demonstrates how I intend to use the COM+ objects.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sampleCOMClass = new SampleCOMObjectClass();
    var cancelToken = new CancelCOMObjectClass();
    try
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            cancelToken.Cancel(); // this method never makes it to COM
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled!");
        });
        sampleCOMClass.LongProcess(cancelToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sampleCOMClass);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cancelToken);
    }
}
```

My long running process correctly checks the cancellation token to determine if we should finish processing, but the `Cancel` method never makes it to the COM+ objects. It is as if the method is blocking, waiting for `LongProcess` to finish. I don't know why it is doing this, because I thought the "Free" threading model allowed the implementations to manage synchronization.

Here is a BitBucket repository with a minimal example to reproduce.
https://bitbucket.org/theonlylawislove/so-blocking-com-call

### **Why is `Cancel` never getting called/blocking?**

**CancelCOMObject**

```
STDMETHODIMP CCancelCOMObject::Cancel(void)
{
    _isCancelled = VARIANT_TRUE;
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CCancelCOMObject::get_IsCancelled(VARIANT_BOOL* pVal)
{
    *pVal = _isCancelled;
    return S_OK;
}
```

**SampleCOMObject**

```
STDMETHODIMP CSampleCOMObject::LongProcess(ICancelCOMObject* cancel)
{
    VARIANT_BOOL isCancelled = VARIANT_FALSE;
    while(isCancelled == VARIANT_FALSE)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        cancel->get_IsCancelled(&isCancelled);
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried marking your COM object as `Both` instead of `Free`?

Comment: In fact, `Neutral` will be more appropriate, if you follow all rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681813(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I just deleted and re-added my objects using the "Neutral" threading model with the same result.

https://bitbucket.org/theonlylawislove/so-blocking-com-call/commits/6aaacaf311758526e6fa0c1da0052cf266ceca16

Is it possible that .NET is not Free/Neutral models? Don't you have to create objects with CoInitializeEx (instead of CoInitialize)? Which one does .NET use internally.

Comment: Obviously isCancelled is not the same variable as _isCancelled.  You can never get to isCancelled, it is a local variable of the method.  You shot your foot by thinking it was a good idea to use two different COM objects.  It was not, there is no hope that the one can find the other unless you hand it a reference.

Comment: Correct, _isCancelled is within the cancel token COM object. The public getter retrieves that value and sets it to the local variable (isCancelled) in LongProcess. The while loop keeps setting the local variable with the one from the cancel COM object.

Comment: How else would I achieve this? Am I going to have to create a COM+ object that handles an internal thread with public Start/Stop methods that don't block?

Comment: @HansPassant, I found the issue. It was very simple. Every time I ask a question, you are always combative and critique things that don't relate to my actual question.

What is your problem?!?!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that my COM+ exe had this.

```
#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
```

Removing that solved my issue.

It is weird that the ATL Simple Object wizard doesn't mention/modify this when specifying "Free" threading model.

It would be nice to know who voted to close this question. It was perfectly valid.

Comment: It's always a good idea to use `CComObjectRootEx` instead of `CComObjectRoot` to specify the threading model explicitly and not depend on that macro.

Comment: .NET handles the creation of the COM objects for me. Is there a way for me to specify, in .NET, to create it with "Ex"?

Comment: This macro has nothing to do with how .NET creates a COM object. It affects how ATL *implements* the plumbing for the COM object's threading model. Use `CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>` in your C++ code.